# Visual Basic Webcam Integration

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, webcam, webcam-capture

I have been trying to integrate a webcam into a visual basic application. The device needs to come on and display the webcam feed on the form and then save the image once the user clicks a button. I have tried using AForge.net but most of the examples I have found have been in C#.

Does any know of any examples or have any tips on getting this to work in Visual Basic. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: So after being able to finally get a working model of what I want on my PC, I tried it on the tablet and was unable to get it to run properly. From what I've read, a windows tablet uses the same driver for both cameras, so the application can't distinguish which to use.

Does anyone know of any kind of work around?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to read this *carefully*: [Ask]

Comment: Try a [code converter](http://converter.telerik.com/).